# save images uploaded by client in this folder in web container using servlet

Tags: java, servlets

[image]

Here we will get multiple images so we will have to store all the images under this folder.
This is the code i am trying but its not working.

```
    for (Part part : request.getParts()) {
                String fileName = filePart.getSubmittedFileName();
                part.write("src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/adimages/" + fileName);
                inputStream=part.getInputStream();
            }
```

Comment: That wouldn't be the right path. Do `request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");` then you know where to place your target directory

Comment: Its returning path :- C:\Users\anoopKumar\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\testFileUpload\   .. Which not something i am looking for

Comment: Ha. that's a perfect illustration of why I use a real server in my config when building webapps. you're going to need a real directory to which you can write.